# Trailing commas disable type checks?

Tags: typescript

The following TypeScript code produces a run-time error:

```
var ns: number[] = ['1',];
alert('' + ns[0].toFixed());
```

I understand that the assignment is fine because the array literal gets typed `any[]`. But why is it `any[]` in the first place?

Is this trailing comma behaviour described anywhere in the language spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array literal can contain undefined items, for example:

```
var a = [,"1",,"3",,,"6"];
```

As this creates an array with values of the type `string` and `undefined`, the type in TypeScript will be `any` to handle both.

Having a single trailing comma in the array will actually not create an undefined value at the end, that is one of the quirks with Javascript. So, in your case the actual array will only have the single string in it, and TypeScript could use the type `string[]` for the array, but I guess that TypeScript doesn't handle this special quirk.

Comment: Why does it suddenly allow `undefined`? Try in Chrome/Node: `['1',] => ['1']` (length 1), `['1',,] => ['1', undefined]` (length 2); i.e. there are no undefined elements in the first instance.

Comment: @coudy: Yes, that is how Javascript behaves. An undefined item at the end is omitted, which is probably there because a single trailing comma added accidentally at the end should not produce an undefined value.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that sounds more likely. So, since trailing commas don't change the array's contents and yet produce very surprising and hard-to-detect typing issues (besides being useful for clean diffs), I take it this is a TS bug.

Comment: This is a bug. The best common type of that array should be `string[]`, not `any[]`.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh, I wouldn't call it a bug. Just Typescript should be seen as a language, which aims to be a 100% compatible, but can't be: as var list = [1, '233', ['a', 2]] does not compile in Typescript either. Due to a different grammar, some things ought to behave different.

Comment: If you assume that ['1', , '2'] should be equivalent to ['1', undefined, '2'], the best common type of those elements is `string[]` according to the spec.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh for this code though... `var ns: number[] = ['1',];` shouldn't this be an error is the array literal is not `number[]`?

Comment: @SteveFenton: The type of `['1',]` is `any[]`, so that is 'assignment compatible' (doc 3.6.3) with `number[]`.

Comment: I can understand why `['1',,'2']` would be typed to `any` (or `string` as Ryan suggests) - but not `['1',]`. In JavaScript, this is an array with one element... the string `'1'`.

Comment: @SteveFenton: Obviously TypeScript doesn't have the same quirk as Javascript where it ignores the last item if it is empty. I can't find anything about the format of an array literal in the language spec, so I can't tell if this is intentional or a bug.